# Usar diretiva de pasta personalizada

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

Criei essa diretiva dentro de um pasta diretivas

```
 app
    |_ diretivas
              |_ click-outside.directive.ts
```

Minha diretiva está assim:

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutSideDirective {
  @Output () clickOutside = new EventEmitter<void>()
  constructor(private elementRref: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick( target ){  
    const clickedInside = this.elementRref.nativeElement.contains( target ) 
   console.log(clickedInside)
    if( !clickedInside ){
      this.clickOutside.emit()
    }
  }

}
```

Chamo assim no meu componente

```
   <div class="form-group has-feedback pull-right" (clickOutSide)="onClickOutside()">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" #iptSearch placeholder="Digite sua pesquisa" (input)="searchTextPendente($event.target.value)" [@campoInput]="campoState">
      <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
   </div>
```

No componente está assim:

```
onClickOutside() {
    console.log('onClickOutside');    
    this.click++;
  }
```

Mas não funciona... Como proceder para arrumar as diretivas apenas em uma pasta específica?

[Esse](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hr9gti) é o código no StackBlitz.

Lembrando que se eu colocar fora da pasta `diretiva`, funciona

**[EDIT]**

Já consegui fazer o console.log mostrar na na classe diretiva o valor, mas se for false era pra emitir, porém não executa nada no componente onde chamo a função `(clickOutSide)="onClickOutside()"`

**[EDIT2]**
Estes são meus arquivos em [html](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/notificacoes/blob/master/notificacao/src/app/notificacao/notificacao.component.html), [ts](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/notificacoes/blob/master/notificacao/src/app/notificacao/notificacao.component.ts) e [diretiva](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/notificacoes/blob/master/notificacao/src/app/diretiva/click-outside.directive.ts)

Comment: Se eu colocar fora da pasta, funciona.. mas eu gostaria de organizar

Comment: Mas mostra algum erro no console?

Comment: Não mostra erro

Comment: Conssegui fazer o console o valor boolean mas no componente onde chama não estou conseguindo executar a função

Comment: Vou te confessar que não entendi bem o que quer fazer com essa função da diretiva, mas, tenta seguir a partir deste exemplo aqui: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-diretiva

Comment: Eu tentei, no Stackblitz funciona, mas no meu projeto, o emit não funciona

Comment: Esse aqui é o meu projeto no git: o [html](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/notificacoes/blob/master/notificacao/src/app/notificacao/notificacao.component.html), o [ts](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/notificacoes/blob/master/notificacao/src/app/notificacao/notificacao.component.ts) e a [diretiva](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/notificacoes/blob/master/notificacao/src/app/diretiva/click-outside.directive.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer funcionar, mas foi da seguinte forma:

O `seletor` da minha diretiva eu coloquei `onClickOutSide`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[onClickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutSideDirective {
  @Output () clickOutside = new EventEmitter<void>()
  constructor(private elementRref: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick( target ){  
    const clickedInside = this.elementRref.nativeElement.contains( target ) 
   console.log(clickedInside)
    if( !clickedInside ){
      this.clickOutside.emit()
    }
  }

}
```

E no html do meu componente eu chamei o seletor definido na minha diretiva

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback pull-right" onClickOutSide (clickOutSide)="onClickOutside()">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" #iptSearch placeholder="Digite sua pesquisa" (input)="searchTextPendente($event.target.value)" [@campoInput]="campoState">
      <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
   </div>
```

No componente.ts ficou assim:

```
onClickOutside() {
    console.log('onClickOutside');    
    this.click++;
  }
```

Desse jeito funcionou

Se alguém passar por isso.. Está ai a dica